# MapReduce Program Map Task Timeout

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am getting this weird error. I have written a wordCount program to count the number of times a word is repeating in a file.

So when I run the MR code on hadoop, the code gets stuck on "Map 100%, Reduce 0%". 
The basic pattern is the first map task times out after 600sec and then once more and the job kills itself.

I checked the Job Tracker and the task is stuck because the Map task is not finishing for the reduce task to start.

I have been trying to fix it for 2 days during which I deleted the original virtual Ubuntu Cloudera and installed it again - so we can be sure it is not a configuration issue.

Any help is appreciated.

The following are the 3 code files.

WordCount.java

```
public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool {

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf =  super.getConf();

    Job job=new Job(conf, "Word Count Job");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

    job.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(WordReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(Boolean.TRUE);

    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Display error message in case insufficient arguments supplied
    if(args.length<2){
        System.out.println("usage: WordCount <Input-Path> <Output-Path>");
    }

    Configuration conf=new Configuration(Boolean.TRUE);

    int i;
    try {
        //Run the overridden 'run' method code
        i = ToolRunner.run(conf, new WordCount(), args);

        //Print usage stats to out
        //ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.out);

        //exit if job cannot start
        System.exit(i);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
}
```

WordMapper.java

```
public class WordMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, FloatWritable> {

@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, 
        Text value,
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, FloatWritable>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    if(!value.toString().trim().isEmpty()){

        StringTokenizer valTokens = new StringTokenizer(value.toString()); 

        while(valTokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            context.write(new Text(valTokens.nextToken()), new FloatWritable(Float.parseFloat("1.00")));
        }
    }   
}
}
```

WordReducer.java

```
public class WordReducer extends Reducer<Text, FloatWritable, Text, FloatWritable> {

@Override
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<FloatWritable> values,
        Reducer<Text, FloatWritable, Text, FloatWritable>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Iterator<FloatWritable> valsIter = values.iterator();
    int i = 0;

    while(valsIter.hasNext()) 
        i++;

    context.write(key, new FloatWritable((float)i));
}
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it worked out, but I hope somebody can explain it. I changed the 'while' loop in _WordMapper.java_ to an _enhanced for loop_ and it worked.

Comment: This highlights the importance of unit tests!! You wasted your own time, strangers, and misunderstood the problem as a Hadoop thing, simply because your too sloppy to take 10 mins to write a unit test. Tsk tsk tsk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line of code:

```
    while(valsIter.hasNext()) 
    i++;
```

valsIter.hasNext checks if there is a next element in the iterator but does not move the position of the pointer. Hence the check always returns true. Unless you call valsIter.next().

Comment: @RaviChandraTimmavajjula You should mark this as Answered.